# can hide JVM termination wizard in eclipse commandline application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jvm, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse commandline application called "DummyApplication" which return IApplication.ExitOK when it is started.
Now I send new Integer(-1) on some abnormal behaviour.
In this case JVM is terminating abnormally, so i get a wizard popsup with text "JVM terminated with exit code : -1 etc..."
Is there any way to hide this wizard? I dont want to use --launcher.supresserror(because this hide all errors and messages of my application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set the Eclipse Application Exit Data Property to empty, which will suppress all the dialogs and messages in commandline mode. And also no logs will be printed in console logs.

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't hide this. The only exit codes supported are `IApplication.EXIT_OK`, `IApplication.EXIT_RESTART` and `IApplication.EXIT_RELAUCH`. Everything else displays the message.

Comment: if no other option i have to use runtime option supresserror. --launcher.supresserror option, will it suppress all the errors to errorlog?

Comment: I don't know what that option does in detail.